# Using a popup box for my "CreateUserWizard" Registration page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

im currently using ASP.NET to create a login/registration system.
I am using the CreateUserWizard for my registration.
IM having difficulties in making the registration link become a pop up because it is coded into my login box.

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" CreateUserText="Register" CreateUserUrl="~/Registration.aspx" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx">
<TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
</asp:Login>
```

if i were to wrap this code around a Div it does not appear.

please help if possible

Comment: by popup do you mean for example a jquery-ui popup? have you tried any of the jquery-ui examples?

Comment: i had a look at the jQuery Modal boxes but i didnt know how to use it lol

Comment: 1. add a html div with an id (for example id="mypopup") 2. Make sure jquery and jquer-ui javascript libraries are included, 3. Now your link should call some javascript like this: `$( "#mypopup" ).dialog();`. If you want things like popups and interactive animations, you need client side javascript code. Having said that I've never used asp.net with `asp:` and `runat="server"` tag. You might want to move to MVC as there will be more examples.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a standalone page, using the sample source code from here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ and try and understand it before trying to apply it to asp.net